# Space or Enter Key on Tabbable DIV: Some browsers don't intercept Keypress

Tags: javascript, html

I need to intercept the keypress of **Enter or Space (13 or 32)** on a Tabbable DIV once it receives focus.

I see the following:

1. Chrome supports both.
2. **Firefox** does not support **Space**.
3. **IE11** does not support **Enter**.

The following snippet can be opened with each browser in turn to see the difference:

```js
$('#buttondiv').keypress(function (e) {
 
    // First log which key was pressed
    console.log(e.keyCode);

  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
   alert('Intercepted Enter or Space');
  }
 });
```

```css
#buttondiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="buttonfocus" onclick="$('#buttondiv').focus()">
  Click here to focus DIV first
</button>

<div id="buttondiv" tabindex="0">
  Press Enter or Space on DIV after focusing
</div>
```

Also, JSFiddle if interested (but JSFiddle won't open in IE):
http://jsfiddle.net/v406agb1/

Comment: Add console.log(e.keyCode); to see, if and which KeyCodes are raised

Comment: Firefox's Space logs 0. IE11's Enter logs nothing at all, doesn't even come to it.

Comment: Try keyup instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `keydown` instead of `keypress`. Here's what the [official documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official
>   specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may
>   differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.
>
> This method is a shortcut for .on( "keypress", handler ) in the first
>   two variations, and .trigger( "keypress" ) in the third.
>
> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. **This is similar to the keydown event, except that
>   modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger
>   keydown events but not keypress events**. Other differences between the
>   two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

```js
$('#buttondiv').keydown(function (e) {
 
    // First log which key was pressed
    console.log(e.keyCode);

  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
   alert('Intercepted Enter or Space');
  }
 });
```

```css
#buttondiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="buttonfocus" onclick="$('#buttondiv').focus()">
  Click here to focus DIV first
</button>

<div id="buttondiv" tabindex="0">
  Press Enter or Space on DIV after focusing
</div>
```